# Using DNS SRV record to access a virtual server without using the port number

Tags: domain-name-system, port-forwarding, srv-record

Let's say that I have a theoretical server located at example.com:3000. Is it possible to get that traffic flowing through a SRV record from myserver.example.com?

I tried the protocol _tcp and the service _http, with the port 3000.

so I end up with something like _http._tcp.myserver and a target of example.com

EDIT: Previous typo in question. Modified from "_html" to "_http".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shoud be _http, as this is the protocol, not _html. The problem is none of the browsers supports SRV records so it will not work anyway.

Have a look here: [Why do browsers not use SRV records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records)

Comment: Sorry. I was typing this question quickly. It was a typo. Issue persists. But thanks for the link with browser incompatibility. Guess I'll have to keep using the port number in the address bar. Highly unfortunate.

Comment: In case your are tired of typing ports your may want to take a look at the various proxy features of web servers like apache or nginx. You could then go ahead and call the services by different domain names and have the web server translate it to the appropriate address and port.